# Passing serial data to Processing using something other than ln to trigger Processing

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, processing-lang, data

I have a Uno program and I can transfer data to Processing using println. In Processing bufferUntil('\n') interprets the ln  as \n, stops buffering, and reads the string until the next '\n'. I would like to use something other than ln to trigger Processing. That way I can use Serial Monitor in the Uno to see serial data when Processing is not running at the same time.

I have searched the net but have not found the technique to use something other than ln. Thanks.

Comment: *ln*? You mean *\n* aka new line character?

Comment: Sounds like you want 2 programs monitoring the same serial port on the PC. What OS are you using? The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question (which is not certain):

- Pick a different "trigger" byte that you won't be sending in your messages.  Maybe *TAB*?
- In your "Processing" program, use: `port.bufferUntil(TRIGGER);`
- In your Arduino sketch, rather than *println*, use *print* to send both your data and the trigger byte:  `Serial.print(your_message); Serial.print(TRIGGER);`

Note that sending binary data will cause this to fail when the data uses the trigger byte.

*From: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println The **println()**
   method sends your output then a CR and NL.  And it seems **bufferUntil()** takes a character on which to trigger:
https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html*